# Mac 10.14.2 Snapshot warning: inode_val, object has invalid bsd flags

Tags: backup, time-machine, oracle

During routine maintenance (running DiskUtil), I received the error message below:

```
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x3024a71c3): invalid bsd_flags (0x10)
```

I did not notice any issues with performance and I am still able to boot the machine. I'm currently in Safe Mode and creating a new Boot Drive so that I may run Drive Genius; however, can anyone kindly advise on how this error may have occurred and/or best practice on how to address it? I do have a very recent Time Machine backup to which I can revert, but I'm not sure what caused the issue and if this will occur again (or escalate from this point).

Comment: It's not an error message, but a warning.  Errors are preceded by the word "error". Are you sure it reads "invalid bad_flags" and not "invalid bsd_flags"? Do you get the warning not only after checking snapshots, but also after `Checking the fsroot tree` and additionally is `The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 appears to be OK` mentioned towards the end?  PS. The warning may also already be present on your Time Machine backup.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the message is "bsd" and not "bad". I receive the warning after checking snapshot, but I don't believe I received this after the fsroot tree check. I did get the message the the volume appears to be ok... Can you help me to understand what the warning means and if I need to take action? I finished running the Disk Genius program; however, it also still showed the warning...

Comment: Sorry, I would post an answer, if I knew.  But if the warnings only appear for the snapshots, you could either wait until they get deleted/thinned, or delete or thin them yourself.  Also your TimeMachine backup might be fine, without warnings in the actual files system.  Personally I'd be inclined not to take warnings too seriously. APFS is still relatively new as well and I'd expect some minor issues here and there.

Comment: @Redarm, this was helpful and I appreciate the reply. I wanted to mark this as helpful and try to close the question, but I can't seem to figure out how. :)

Comment: I'd like to see a proper answer to your question.  Maybe a way to find an object by "oid" (object id?).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Olleg's link in his answer, it becomes clear that to find the file referenced in Disk Utility's error message has to be converted to an inode number first.
The "oid" (object ID) is hexadecimal, while the "inum" (inode number) is decimal.

You can either [manually convert](https://owlcation.com/stem/Convert-Hex-to-Decimal) it to decimal, or use [one of the many online converters](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.htm).

In your case with an OID 0x3024a71c3, the converted inode number is 12923335107.
To search for the file with the inode number (inum), launch Terminal from /Applications/Utilities/, or find it via Spotlight and type:

```
find / -inum 12923335107 -print 2> /dev/null
```

This should show you the file in question, including path, in its output.

In Olleg's link this seems common for the OneDrive folder.

The inode is also shown, when running a file system check with the debug flag (-d) on the container: `fsck_apfs -d`
Example: [APFS: fsroot tree is invalid after Time Machine backup - how to recover and avoid in the future?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311263/apfs-fsroot-tree-is-invalid-after-time-machine-backup-how-to-recover-and-avoi)

Comment: This finds a path but the Terminal doesn't stop "working", that is it doesn't get back to the starting state where I can input any command. What should I do once I found the path (which is by the way something in the Trash folder...)?

Comment: `^C`, or `⌘.` (cmd+period, or ctrl+C) should stop find.  For other exits from various commands see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45646/how-do-i-exit-or-cancel-a-bad-bash-command

Answer (score 2):

For those who don't want to do a clean install of macOS, here's what I did. After having the same problem, and finding that it has definitely everything to do with OneDrive:

1. Download everything from OneDrive to Mac, if that was not the case already.
2. Quit OneDrive.
3. Uninstall OneDrive, I used [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) app. Make sure to delete the OneDrive app, all the files related to it, the login items and launch agents. App Cleaner app makes this part easy.
4. Delete all keychain items related to OneDrive.
5. Delete the login item permission from System Preferences → Users & Groups → Your username → Login Items.
6. Copy all the folders and files from the OneDrive folder to an external HDD. The OneDrive folder is usually directly on your user main folder. Everything that was previously on OneDrive should be there.
7. Delete the OneDrive folder.
8. Empty the Trash.
9. Copy all the contents of the OneDrive folder from the external HDD back to Mac, where you want them to reside. **This is an important part**, this copy and restore operation to an external HDD is what resets whatever mess OneDrive did with the permissions or flags of the offending files.
10. Verify MacintoshHD with Disk Utility's First Aid, Onyx or with the command line on Terminal. Whatever method you were using that made you realize about the `inode_val` problem as per this thread discussion. You shouldn't have more warnings, but in case you do, those warnings are pointing to files that had to do something with OneDrive at some point in time.

    So what I followed Redman's Jan 23 at 18:00 instructions above to locate in Finder the first item that appears in the list of warnings from the verify operation, then copied the entire folder containing the file to the external HDD. I copied the whole folder because it is probable that there are other files in that folder that generate the warning, because they could have something to do with OneDrive in the past. Then deleted the folder on Mac, restore it from the external HDD and verified again. I had to do this around five or six times because those were files that I moved to OneDrive or synched them or something in the past and of course I didn't remember.
11. Delete the contents of the OneDrive folder on your external HDD if you want.
12. Remember to always doubt about the quality of Microsoft products, some are good products but unfortunately others are very low quality.

The whole process took me about half an hour, but I got rid of the warnings.

I used a 13" Mid 2015 MacBook Pro running macOS 10.14.4.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here. I has the same problem, now it's fixed.
https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/913525-onedrive-on-mac/suggestions/36302779-remove-warning-inode-val-object-invalid-bsd-fl

Comment: On Ask Different we prefer answers that are self-contained. Can you extract the salient details behind that link and write them out here? Links rot and then knowedge is lost, but a summary solves that problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured out a solution to the dreaded "Warning: inode_val:....." fiasco. This same issue has been plaguing my 2018 MB Pro for several months now, until now I finally had the time to dive it into the issue and created a resolution, I hope the below works for you all as well. Apple and Microsoft really need to get their acts together to create a patch for this problem, such a PITA complete loss users of data, information and time troubleshooting.

For starters, I am not certain what set this off to begin with but it appears to be 2 things possibly, some type of file or file name corruption within OneDrive which is also connected to drive imagery backup solutions such as TimeMachine and Carbon Copy, which I use all three, OneDrive, TimeMachine and Carbon Copy. When running Disk Utility from "Command-R" I would get the "Warning: inode_val:......" and also noticed that my 1 TB ssd was nearly maxed out with over 500 GB compromised by System Data, the highest System Data tapped out one day at 650 GB (See Below Screenshot).

My Troubleshooting: After multiple attempts and several variations of completely wiping my ssd and OS, starting with a clean install these were my results:

- First Attempt: Command-R | wipe ssd and attempted back up from TimeMachine partition resulted in a completely failed restoration process, all TimeMachine back-ups were corrupted and would not work.
- Second Attempt: Command-R | wipe ssd and attempted backup from Carbon Copy partition completed restored my device and all files but cloned the same corrupted files over from OneDrive resulting in the same "Warning: inode_val:....." error when running Disk Utility.
- Third Attempt: Command-R | wipe ssd and this time did not connect and external Thunderbolt 3 devices, and conducted a fresh install of OS Mojave from the Apple Server. Presto! Warning: inode_val: problem solved, after booting up the the fresh OS install, I installed OneDrive waited for all files download, then restarted the machine, Command-R to run Disk Utility and boom no more errors. So in short, Do Not try and restore you machine from previous corrupted backup sources as this will bring the same corrupted files back to your new install. With the new installed I also recovered 75% of my compromised ssd storage. One final note, I am completely abandoning the use of TimeMachine, this is no longer a reliable or stable solution for file or system restoration.(See Final Screenshots)